# Get first <li> WITHOUT jquery

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

This may have been asked, but scrolling through about 40+ search results reveals only the jQuery solution. Let's say I want to get the first item in an unordered list and apply a new text color to it, and it alone. This is simple with jQuery.

Markup ->

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

With jQuery ->

```
$("ul > li:first").css("color", "blue");
```

Question is, how do I achieve this **without** jQuery?

---

**SOLUTION:**
I found this method to work across all browsers (inc IE7+) ->

```
document
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("li")[0]
    .style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` *(IE7 and lower not supported)*:

```
document.querySelector("ul > li")
```

---

Or `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")[0]
```

---

Or `getElementsByTagName`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]
        .getElementsByTagName("li")[0]
```

---

The best way to change style IMO is to set a class. You do this by setting *(or expanding)* the `.className` property of the resulting element.

Otherwise you can set the individual styles using the `.style` property.

---

***update***

As [@Randy Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1750282/randy-hall) pointed out, perhaps you wanted to first `li` of all `ul` elements. In that case, I would use `querySelectorAll` like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li:first-child")
```

Then iterate the result to set the style.

---

To use `getElementsByTagName`, you could do this:

```
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");

var lis = [].map.call(uls, function(ul) {
    return ul.children[0];
});
```

You'll need an `Array.prototype.map()` shim for IE8 and lower.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("ul").getElementsByTagName("li")[0]` - your example only gets first `li` of first `ul`, this gets first `li` of every `ul`, just for clarity. Asker didn't specify if they were looking for only the first `ul` or not.

Comment: @RandyHall: Yes, all my examples only give the first one. Good point. I don't know what the intent is.

Answer (score 4):

```
document
    .getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("li")[0]
    .style.color = "blue";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change style only, use CSS :first-child

```
ul > li:first-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

works even in IE7
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/trxe3/

Comment: Be careful using this though. I believe it is new as of CSS3 and may not be supported in some older browsers.

Comment: @Tymoteusz Czech OK, I guess I was wrong, but quirksmode does say that there is a catch to the `first-child` selector in IE<9. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t17

Comment: @jdwire it's CSS 2.1. Issues may occur if you create this dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Using the basic DOM operations:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('id of ul');
var child = ul.childNodes[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the only valid child of `<ul>` is `<li>`, you can do this:

```
var firstLI = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].children[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), depending on your needs. Smaller than jQuery, but handles all your selector normalization.

Comment: Yeah I think jQuery actually uses a version of sizzle for it's selector, I'm looking for the pure javascript alternative.

Comment: jQuery does utilize sizzle - sizzle is the "pure javascript" fallback for cross-browser element selection. If this is the only function you need to worry about, sizzle is too much. But if you have several functions that use complex selectors and you need to support older browsers, sizzle is VERY fast, VERY well proven, and pretty small. It's not a library so much like jQuery or Mootools, it's just a normalization of a single functionality.

Comment: I agree, and if you need to select multiple elements it's very useful. But the normalization you mention is what makes it non-'pure'!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this is enough:

```
document.querySelector("ul > li:first-child");
```