# Dynamic <ul> and <li> on hover in <ul> show <li>

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 `<ul>` and each `<ul>` element have 1 hidden `<li style="display:none;">` hover on 1 `<ul>` i want to show only `<li>` of which that `<ul>` is hover

Problem is that when i hover on 1 `<ul>` element it will hover on all 3 `<ul>` element and display all `<li>` element.

Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function chh()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("ul").length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[i].onmouseover = function()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)
            {
                document.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="chh();">
<ul>
Friend Request Sent
<li style="display:none;">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
<ul>
Friend Request Sent
<li style="display:none;">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
<ul>
Friend Request Sent
<li style="display:none;">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/vZeP4/

Comment: i show here only three `<ul>` i have 50+ `<ul>` calling from database dynamically so i cant use id's and classes for this thats why i try something this

Comment: I personally prefer the CSS solution. This will allow the hover to work on all browsers

Comment: both will perfectly work on all browsers

Comment: Some mobile browsers might have issues with the JS + not all people allow JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop goes through all the `<li>`s and sets their display to `block`. You need to pick the `<li>` that is inside the `<ul>` hovered upon.

A quick fix would be:

```
function chh()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("ul").length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[i].onmouseover = function()
        {
            this.childNodes[1].style.display = "block";         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I used `childNodes[1]` because the text node "Friend Request Sent" is considered `childNodes[0]`. A better way is to look for the first `<li>` using jquery's `$(this).find("li").css("display","block")`. Doing the same task with native javascript is also possible but will be messier, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178028/get-first-li-without-jquery

Comment: Add that info to the answer. You'll have more cahnge of it being read

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort both answer work perfectly but i prefer this one

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with css, without using any javascript.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="message">Friend Request Sent</li>
    <li class="cancel">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="message">Friend Request Sent</li>
    <li class="cancel">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="message">Friend Request Sent</li>
    <li class="cancel">Cancel Request</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul > .cancel {
    display: none;
}
ul:hover > .cancel {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vZeP4/4/)**

Also, notice that I have put `Friend Request Sent` within an `li`. This is because all children of a `ul` must be an `li`. Having anything else in there is invalid html.