# finding the first li of an ul to set its class

Tags: javascript

ok so I managed to print a whole ul doing this:

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("ul#treatments-list")[0]);
```

Now my problem is to reach the first li to give it a className.

Comment: The *ul* in *ul#treatments-list* seems redundant given that the ID must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul#treatments-list > li:first-child")
```

Try this. Here is an answer with a similar problem [Get first <li> WITHOUT jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178028/get-first-li-without-jquery)

Comment: gives me `Exception from Tracker recompute function: undefined is not a function
TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the selectors API, there are good 'ol DOM 1 methods:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('treatments-list');
var firstLI;
if (ul) {
  firstLI = ul.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
}
```

or

```
  firstLI = ul.children[0]
```

but *children* requires IE 9 or better.

In one line:

```
var firstLI = document.getElementById('treatments-list').getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
```

but that assumes there is an element with ID *treatments-list* in the document.

#### Edit

The following works for me. Given:

```
<ul id="treatments-list">
 <li id="first">first
 <li>not first
 <li>not first
 <li>not first
 <li>not first
</ul>
```

then:

var firstLI = document.getElementById('treatments-list').getElementsByTagName('li')[0];

console.log(firstLI.textContent); // first

The other suggested code works too.

Comment: I have `<ul id="treatments-list">` but `firstLI` returns `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll("ul#treatments-list").find("li:first"))
console.log($( "ul#treatments-list li:first" ));
```

try .first() ?

Answer (score -1):

$('#yourUlId li:first').attr('class','yourClassName');