# Get first level li from ul

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I thought this must be easy but couldn't find a way to get the first level `<li>` elements. I've tried like so:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>
    C
    <ul>
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
      <li>C3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

But that gives me all `<li>` elements including `C1, C2` etc.

I would like to get only the elements

```
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
```

How to achieve that with vanilla javascript?
**Please no jQuery**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first <li> WITHOUT jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178028/get-first-li-without-jquery)

Comment: @SureshMaurya that is only how to get the first `<li>` not all the `<li>s` from first level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the outer `<ul>` an identifier (or a class) and select them using `ul#myId > li` (or `ul.myId > li`) Or just specifiy that you don't mean the inner ul in any other way, e.g. `body > ul > li`.