# Target first level ul li elements only

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists

This solution isn't going to work since I have no control over adding a class/id to the ul element: [Get first level li from ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036800/get-first-level-li-from-ul)

Given that the parent ul has no id/class, can css be written to target only the first level li?  If not, how could it be done?

This is the html:

```
<ul>
<li id="acomment-62" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="62">
    <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
   <ul>
        <li id="acomment-65" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="65">
            <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
            <div class="acomment-meta"></div>
            <div class="acomment-content"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li id="acomment-63" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="63">
    <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
   <ul>
        <li id="acomment-66" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="66">
            <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
            <div class="acomment-meta"></div>
            <div class="acomment-content"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li id="acomment-64" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="64">
    <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
   <ul>
        <li id="acomment-67" class=" comment-item" data-bp-activity-comment-id="67">
            <div class="bb-activity-more-options-wrap action"></div>
            <div class="acomment-meta"></div>
            <div class="acomment-content"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with CSS alone. There's a few ways you can do it. Here is one of them and [a working codepen](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/vYjBgpd?editors=1100) so you can mess around with it yourself.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item with list 1
    <ul>
        <li>Sub 1</li>
        <li>Sub 2</li>
        <li>Sub 3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item with list 2
    <ul>
        <li>Sub 1</li>
        <li>Sub 2</li>
        <li>Sub 3</li>
        <li>Sub List
            <ul>
                <li>Sub list item 1</li>
                <li>Sub list item 2</li>
                <li>Sub list item 3</li>            
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
```

CSS

```
li {
color: red;
}

li li {
    color: initial;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew.  The method of applying a property to all of the li's would probably lead to a performance hit; that is, assuming that there are hundreds of thousands or even millions of comments (which is what this example represents)? I think a better solution if this can't be done via css efficiently would be jQuery.

Comment: @QuintRahaman if you're loading millions of comments I'd imagine CSS is the least of your concerns performance-wise. Whilst descendants are not especially performant selectors in CSS terms I'd be highly surprised if jQuery could outperform CSS in applying styling to HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how supported this is but you *could* apply the style to **all** `li` and then override that style to target any descendant `li`

EG.

```css
li li {
  color: initial;
}

li {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>
    C
    <ul>
      <li>C1</li>
      <li>C2</li>
      <li>C3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Will this work when each li can have nested ul li's which they themselves can have nested ul li's?  This use case reflects "comments" where "replies" are allowed, etc.

Comment: Test it and check would be my advice.